# stop/exit for loop on first reject promise in angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop, angular-promise

I have tried all various way to do so but still didnt figure out how to resolve this.

I have a method `iterator` that return promise; this method runs for x times in a loop. I want if `iterator` return rejected promise than it should stop the execution and goes to error bloc.

I have tried with below approach taken from [this SO asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31801982/break-out-of-promise-block-in-a-for-loop)but this send the error but execute till the x times.

```
var foo = function(formdata) {
   var d = $q.defer();
   CallService.init()
  .then(function(response) {
    return CallService.fun1(formdata);
  })
  .then(function(response) {
     var row = {1:'one', 2:'two', 3: 'three' };
     var promiseArray = [];
     if (<key condition true>) {            
        var promise = Object.keys(row).map(function(i) {
            return iterator(i, row[i]).then(function(response){
                promiseArray.push(response);
                }, function(err){
                return $q.reject(err);
            });
        });
        return $q.all(promise); // reject if anyone is rejected, otherwise resolve
    }
    else {
        d.reject({
            message: "key condition failed."
        });
    }
    return d.promise;  
})
 .then(successHandler)
 .catch(errorHandler);
};
```

and here is the function that being called for each loop

```
var iterator = function(num, data) {
    var d = $q.defer();
    CallService.fun3()
    .then(function(response) {
        return CallService.fun4(data)
    })
    .then(function(response) {
       d.resolve(num);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {           
       d.reject(err);
    });
    return d.promise;
};
```

I want that if `iterator` send reject for the first time than it should not go for the next and break the loop;

how to  achieve that?

I have also tried this way

```
var d = $q.defer();
for (var k in row) {
    if (isCalled) break;
    var promise = iterator(k, row[k]);
    promise.then(function(response) {
        promiseArray.push(response);
    }, function(err) {
        isCalled = true;
        d.reject(err);
    });
}
if (!isCalled && promiseArray.length > 0) {
    console.log('after for loop', promiseArray);
    d.resolve(promiseArray);
}

return d.promise;
```

but this also fails.. it always executes for all the loop in spite of any reject promise.

### edit

I have tried with .reduce method but this is somehow works but I need to send promiseArray ( if any entry is there ) alog with the error. here is my working code.

```
var first_promise = $q.resolve();
var start_promise = Object.keys(row).reduce(function(promise, key){
      return promise.then(function(result){
          if(angular.isDefined(result)) // as first_promise results undefined
              promiseArray.push(result);
          return iterator(key, row[key]);
      });
 }, first_promise);
 start_promise.then(function(res){
     return $q.when(promiseArray);
 }).catch(function(err){
     return $q.reject();
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer after clarification. Op wants his asynchronous calls to run synchronous. Stopping when they hit a rejection.

Check out [this blogpost](https://techanand.wordpress.com/2015/07/04/sequential-execution-of-promises-in-angularjs/). That decorator seems to do exactly that.

Comment: in your plunker, you explicitly set to exit from function based on key condition but in my case; it need to define it when reject comes first

Comment: So you want your asynchronous calls to run synchronous? Stopping when they hit a rejection?

Comment: yes exactly i want that. let me update what i have done so far

Comment: Check out [this blogpost](https://techanand.wordpress.com/2015/07/04/sequential-execution-of-promises-in-angularjs/). That decorator seems to do exactly that.

Comment: this is quite interating , but how do O call `$q.seqAll()`? on `$q.seqAll(iterator);`